# python regex for substring list of number

Tags: python, regex

Giving this string:

`numbers 1 2 10 20`

where the amount of numbers might be 1 or more, how can I get only the numbers? (i.e expression that would return:

`[1, 2, 10, 20]`

My closest try was:

```
re.findall(r'numbers (\d +)', 'numbers 1 2 10 20')
>>> ['1 ']
```

Edit:

The case above is not telling the whole story so I will explain a bit more.

I have a list of strings, and I need to first figure out whether one of them is matching the pattern `number X Y Z` as explained above.
If such a string is indeed in that list I want to extract from it only the numbers.

I can do it in multiple steps but I wonder If I can use regex here to get what I want with a one-liner.

Examples:

Let's assum that the function `func1(list)` is our magic function that do all I requires.

```
l1 = ['letters a b c', 'numbers 1 12 6']
l2 = ['animalas dog cat', 'colors red blue']

>>> func1(l1)
OUT: [1, 12, 6]

>>> func2(l1)
OUT: []
```

Comment: Uhm, `is.digit()` ?

Comment: `print(re.findall(r"(\d+)", "numbers 1 2 10 20"))` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
strr = "numbers 1 2 10 20"
```

Uhm:

```
print(''.join([n for n in strr if n.isdigit()]))
```

OR

```
print([int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', strr)])
```

OR

```
import re
print(map(int, re.findall('\d+', strr)))
```

OUTPUT:

> [1, 2, 10, 20]

Based on OP's EDIT:

You need to match the string first before you fetch all the digits out of it:

```
if re.match("numbers .*"+ r'\b\d+\b', strr):
    print("String pattern matched, Now extracting..")
```

Hence:

```
import re

def func1(strrList):
        for strr in strrList:        
            if re.match("numbers .*"+ r'\b\d+\b', strr):
                print("String pattern matched, Now extracting..")
                print(map(int, re.findall('\d+', strr)))
            else:
                print("String pattern failed to match.")


l1 = ['letters a b c', 'numbers 1 12 6']
l2 = ['animalas dog cat', 'colors red blue']

func1(l1)
```

OUTPUT:

> String pattern failed to match.
>
> String pattern matched, Now extracting..
>
> [1, 12, 6]

Comment: Please see my edit, the `numbers` prefix is important to the issue i am facing.

Comment: @AndyThomas Could you provide a elaborated example? Perhaps with a sample I/O?

Comment: I have added I/O exmple.

Comment: @AndyThomas edited!

Comment: Thank you, this is of course will do the trick. However I hoped that there is a way to catch the `numbers` prefix and extract only the numbers after it. From your answer I conclude that there isn't. Right?

Comment: @AndyThomas added the complete example.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because as I said it is matching my requirements but I am still hoping to find out about a one-liner call for this issue :) Thank you.